# Can I connect multiple STM32 to single CAN transceiver?

Tags: stm32, can

*TL;DR: This question is about saving unnecessary CAN transceivers by sharing one among 3-4 equal MCUs on a small, single board.*

Imaginary situation:
A board with multiple, equal, CAN-capable STM32-MCUs needs to chat with other equally-made boards via CAN bus.
There's one transceiver on each board (most probably an MCP2562FD), meant to be connected to all MCUs in parallel, sharing bus access.
Please see the following pseudo-schematic for clarification:

[image: Pseudoschematic of two multi-MCU-boards connected via CAN]

The "secondary MCUs" on the left half will "just passively listen" and use individual ID filters to only get relevant data for their task.

The respective "main MCU" will be the only active communicator on each board, officially talk / respond / ACK on the bus.

The point is to reduce transceiver IC count per board. Normally, I would put a dedicated transceiver for each MCU. To me, however, a CAN transceiver (not: controller) looks like an "active access point" / "medium translator" that's not necessarily bound to be connected to a single client MCU only. I further assume, that if the main MCU was able to understand a message (and "ACKed" it), the secondary µCs should have received it correctly, too - since all lines are kept short and away from noise, and interference should be most likely to happen on the other side of the transmitter. The tx lines of the secondaries will be omitted, most probably, to enforce passivity.

To me, this concept looks feasible, electronically and logically. Yet, I'm unable to find any resource describing that it could work or wouldn't at all.
If any CAN / STM32 pro could shed some light on this, point me to the right direction (*), name pitfalls, confirm or refute my thoughts, I'd highly appreciate that!

Thank you for your time and attention!

(*) without discussing the multi-MCU-approach as a whole or switching to / introducing other means of multi processor communication - I *love* and *want* the high abstraction level by ID filtering and mailboxes all-in-hardware goodness ;)

Comment: You are amplifying, doubling down,  and exponentiating the shared media issues that plague shared media  busses like CAN and then removing the only element (transceiver) used to mitigate the trouble. But there is no technical reason you can't make this work. If you are looking for cost savings be sure to do a true decision matrix taking into account the cost of design complexity because this will cost much more than 4 transceivers a board to implement and support.

Comment: One downside is basically worrying about firmware update or any chip stepping bricking your boards due to a very fragile stack configuration that needs to synchronize multiple ucs per board. This design better be worth what you will be throwing at it.

Comment: @crasic Umm well obviously there's a lot of things to consider with every component choice. Right now ST can't deliver STM32F without huge lead time delays, for example. So right now I wouldn't use STM32 in new designs, until ST sort out their delivery times. And that is not a technical reason.

Comment: Your design will be as fragile as a house of cards, supply chain issues aside, this is not a professional approach barring some hugely important demand.

Comment: @crasic There's not really enough information to tell. I've done similar projects where a modular design with multiple modules was redrawn with same schematics into a single, specialized PCB. They shared CAN communication which now became on-board, though in my case each node could send. But the reasoning here was "don't break the working system design just change the mechanical layout". Which in turn meant faster time to market. To merge the 4 different MCUs into one would have been a big software project, likely 1 year of extra work.

Comment: Also "one super processor that can do everything in the world" is a pretty brittle design too, because that one will be much more complex software-wise.

Comment: @Lundin I don't think I proposed such a solution or suggested a monolithic approach, ultimately it seems to be the perfectly disharmonious mix of complex+highly integrated (4 MCU's on one board means the solution can support such cost), and petty+cheap (wishing to save 1-3 transceiver per board, breaking abstractions and increasing support cost). This, in my experience, points to poor communication of requirements and I am encouraging OP to focus on their requirements. I see this question as an example of the X-Y problem, it seeks a system solution with a hardware hack.

Comment: Thank you all for bringing in additional interesting aspects to consider.
I wanted this design to essentially behave like a single MCU/node to the other nodes. One MCU is bidirectionally connected to the transceiver. Now my design differs in only a single point: there are more MCUs transparently "spying on the local representation" (rx line) of the bus traffic and doing their tasks accordingly - I'm just adding ears. That's why I don't really see @crasic's (-> worsening the plague) points. Of course I could be wrong - that's why I ask here ;) but I don't really see: where exactly and why?

Comment: Second aspect is the transceiver: Isn't it just a "bridge" IC essentially translating the electrical representation of a bus protocol into a format (differential, in this case) that's able to withstand harsh interference and long lines? This idea isn't meant to be a "hack", it just felt counterintuitive and unnecessary to put lots of these bridges right beside each other on the same board to access the same bus on the "high side".

Comment: With a transceiver CAN trivially resolves bus contention in a guaranteed safe way using dominant zero open collector signaling.  A slave simply needs to sample the bus state to see if it has won the contention, in this game of ro sham bo electrical 0 beats electrical 1 and this is why Id 0 will always beat all in a response even if the start at the same time. This beautiful dance is integrated into a transceiver and enables a basic push pull uart interface with the controller. Reimplementing a portion of this intrinsic behavior on the controller side may be more challenging than expected.

Comment: Effectively each can controller drives it's tx pin and then checks to see if rx matches tx, the transceiver takes care of the electrical details to make this work safely . Now you eliminate this coupling and there is a chance, albeit manageable, that two of your listening mcus attempt to drive the bus , this is usually safe because after a small period of time it will sample the bus and if the rx doesn't match tx it will give up transmission assuming it lost contention. The transceiver makes it all safe. In your design this would result in undefined behavior or even a short circuit failure.

Comment: This could happen for example, if a bug freezes the pin in a state or reconfigures the pin. In one case it results in a possibly recoverable error vs in the other case a possible burned board.

Comment: What's the "triangle" in the schematic supposed to be? So manner of OP amp? A diode? The Rx line is already driven by the CAN transceiver, you shouldn't place any components there, not even pull resistors.

Comment: @Lundin It's a fast logic line driver / buffer, since there are logic levels. It's job is to make the line over to the secondary MCUs one-way. So, any pin misbehaviour that could happen by bad flashes, hardware errors (like crasic pointed out above) etc. will not degrade correct CAN reception of the main MCU. It will not alter data, but only introduce a small 300-500ps time lag. Since these don't talk to the bus, the time lag shouldn't mean anything.

Comment: @Zod If any MCU at any point starts driving that pin, then something is very wrong. Aren't all STM32 parts set as input out of reset? And why do you wish to continue business as usual if there are severe problems in the system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, I want the "secondary µCs" on each board to "just passively
> listen" and use individual ID filters to only see relevant data (each
> free CPU cycle counts).

Yes, if you are doing this then there is no problem having multiple micro controllers with their respective CAN_TX and CAN_RX pins tied together. As you mentioned, you should ensure they are set to passive mode if possible (which the STM32 does).

Note that even if they didn't have a passive mode, it should still be okay to connect the lines together (though some series resistors on CAN_TX would be prudent) as each CAN controller will ACK every message or generate error frames at the same point anyway. Also note that most CAN controllers will ACK any valid frame they see, regardless of whether it is subsequently filtered or not. Filtering is a higher level operation whereas the ACK bit is there to provide basic connectivity checking for the transmitting node (and not a whole lot else in practice).

Comment: Thank you for the insight and pointing out details about the ACK! This will make me consider implementing a more high-level ACK mechanism for critical msgs.

Answer (score 2):

There's two circumstances in which a node's CAN controller will send things on the bus even if it hasn't been told to send any data frames:

- To set ACK bits in any incoming frame.
- To send error frames in case it spots errors (stuffing, bit errors etc).

So if all your MCUs share the Tx and Rx lines, you must make sure that the passive nodes do not do any of the above. Assuming ST BxCAN controller, then apparently it has a "silent mode" where any transmission from the "silent" node is internally looped to Rx and CAN Tx output is held recessive.

This assuming that the "silent" node doesn't go haywire if someone external starts pulling its Tx line to dominant level. In case doing so affects the error counter on the "silent" node then this design might not be feasible, so I'd just leave the Tx pin on each "silent" node unconnected.

And yeah it should work to have your active node only doing the ACK. The silent nodes will pick up the ACK from the CANH/CANL side.

Answer (score 2):

Good news: I have a solution that deals brilliantly with the shared CAN problem, and it will make your overall design much simpler.

*Use a single, more powerful MCU.*

If you can't, you'll have to explain in some detail why, because I see your question as a yet another XY problem: you look for a solution to some detail without examining (in the question) why that detail even makes sense to begin with. Using a single MCU instead of 4 of them solves that problem, and solves a lot of other problems you don't even know you have (yet).

> each free CPU cycle counts

That tells me that you're using an underpowered MCU for the job. You'll likely get higher power efficiency per MIPS from a more powerful MCU as well, so if you worry about power consumption, one more powerful chip beats several less powerful ones (assuming they were fully utilized).

I have had a "simple" design with 4 MCUs, networked via SPI. It turned out to be way more trouble than it was worth - a single, more powerful chip, made everything miles easier. That design never left the stage of a limited prototype run, and I'm glad.

> I want the "secondary µCs" on each board to "just passively listen"

Passive listening is pretty much the default operating mode for CAN, since flipping acknowledgment bits isn't necessary unless the transmitter software requires them. In plenty of designs CAN can be used as pretty much a "broadcast" medium, where every node transmits as needed, and nodes interested in stuff listen to it. Since, presumably, all nodes are there for a reason, it won't be typical to have some node prolong inter-transmission periods ("back off") if there are "no listeners" as determined by lack of acknowledgments.

With a fixed network structure and a fixed function of the overall system, each node would send reports while following some link utilization budget assigned to it, and it wouldn't back off just because no listeners provide ACKs. Many CAN implementations do signal a lack of ACK as an "error", but that's an entirely arbitrary name with no other consequence typically, and is only an "error" if your code that sends the messages will treat it that way. The CAN adapter makes sure to report lack of ACK, since the spec requires it to detect and signal it to higher layers. The higher layers are free to ignore it in purely broadcast systems where the nodes don't need to establish connections on top of CAN (and thus establish state that tracks presence of receiver(s)). ACKs from very many nodes are one of worst cases for CAN signal integrity, since they dramatically lower the bus impedance.

Comment: That's where I came from - one of the most obvious approaches ;) But I'm not that much into "One big CPU for all tasks", especially when there are time critical things running. My specific needs / reasons to segment the code / load / tasks into parts for multiple MCUs working in parallel are more important than saving surplus transceivers. This is not to discuss my general design, but only about the question: *can* I save them, and if yes, how? ;)

Comment: Why do you think saving those transceivers will actually save you money? What's the volume? If you, for example, spend 8 weeks designing and validating the transceiver-less "fakecan", will there be savings? That's lot of transceivers for that! A single chip MCU doesn't mean that you only get one core - there are plenty of multicore designs. So you have to provide some substance to the claim that you actually need physically separate chips vs. multicores, and that dealing with those chips will be somehow easier than dealing with many cores (even if different cores, eg.. Cortex-M and Cortex-A).

Comment: Basically it seems to me that somehow you made the decision to use multiple separate chips without considering the entirety of the system, and are now trying to "back-substantiate" this design, whereas it looks like the design was not complete to begin with. You're very focused on the transceiver-less CAN problem, but that seems like a book case of target fixation that often derails projects.

Comment: >"So you have to provide some substance to the claim that you actually need physically separate chips vs. multicores" ..
No, I don't - because that's not my question.
When multiple MCUs on a board can perfectly listen silently to the incoming rx of the transmitter, which only costs me five minutes to lay out some traces on the board accordingly, then it's worth having asked the question whether it works.

Comment: > "You're very focused on the transceiver-less CAN .."
Yes, I *am* focussed to discuss my original question, not my other design decisions.
And no, it is not transceiver-less. In no way. Possible misunderstanding somewhere? I'll see if / how I can add an image to my original post to clarify.

Comment: "...since flipping acknowledgment bits isn't necessary" This is wrong, doing this is absolutely necessary in order to get a functioning bus. Suppose there is only one external node (point-to-point). If no node does an ACK, then all communication on the bus will die. This is specified by the CAN standard, you shouldn't (and probably can't) make some home-brewed version of the controller that doesn't signal errors upon no ACK.

Comment: This is mandatory behavior, see for example the CAN2.0B "Bosch" spec p.9: "Acknowledgement. All receivers check the consistency of the message being received and will acknowledge a consistent message and flag an inconsistent message." So it isn't "Many CAN implementations do signal a lack of ACK" but rather "_conforming_ CAN implementations do signal a lack of ACK".